# If 'ID' from Table A is in 'PID' column of Table B then I want to exclude both records from table B in result set

Tags: sql, sql-server

If 'ID' from Table A is in 'PID' column of Table B then I want to exclude both records from table B in result set. Currently, when I am join 2 tables on A.PUID = B.PUID and A.ID <> B.PID 2nd record from B table is showing up in result.

Table A:

```
PUID      PID          SYSTEMCODE      ID

100000  701848421         A         3207479
```

Table B:

```
PUID          PID        SYSTEMCODE

100000       3207479     B

100000       6805875     B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `not exists`

```
select * from A 
where not exists (select 1 from B where A.puid=B.puid and A.id=B.pid)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude just based on the matching id, you would use:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from b
                  where a.id = b.pid
                 );
```

However, you seem to want to exclude all *pid*s where there is a match:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from b join
                       a a2
                       on a2.id = b.pid
                  where p.pid = a.pid
                 );
```